# Twig translate a string which contains parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

In my Twig project I use translation from .yaml files. The text which I need to translate is found in a .html.twig file and says, for example,

"My text for translation contains a {{parameter}} to translate."

I know that I can replace this whole string with a key word, for example - to_translate %parameter% to_translate2, and I can use the translation from my .yaml file like this

to_translate: "My text for translation contains a"
to_translate2: "to translate"

And the parameter will be passed. However, how can I do this without breaking the sentence in so many parts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I didn't get your point, but you can add as many parameters as you want ?

Yaml file:

```
my_translation_key: Hello %firstname%, %lastname%, welcome here !
```

In Twig:

```
{{ 'my_translation_key' | trans({
        '%firstname%': 'John',
        '%lastname%': 'Doe'
    }) }}
```

If what you want is to get nested blocks in your translations, you can probably try something like this:

Yaml file:

```
my_translation_key: Hello %firstname%, %lastname%, %welcome% !
welcome_block: welcome %where%
```

In Twig:

```
{% set welcome = 'welcome_block' | trans({'%where%': 'here'}) %}
{{ 'my_translation_key' | trans({
        '%firstname%': 'John',
        '%lastname%': 'Doe',
        '%welcome%': welcome
    }) }}
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was I use stand-alone Twig and maybe some symfony parts did not work. So now I pass the parameter using {% trans with { '%var%': var } %}translate{% endtrans %} and in the .yaml file I have translate: my sentence %var% Thanks!!!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should try this :

```
{{ ('My text for translation contains a '~parameter)|trans }}
```

In [Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) :

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello " ~ name > ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.

Comment: You should never concatenate a parameter with a string to translate because it makes the translation key depend on the parameter, and thus the translation key becomes unpredictable. The correct way is : `{{ 'My text for translation contains a %parameter%'|trans({'%parameter%': parameter}) }}`